# I've inherited the Craft website and the developer is long gone. How do I access the templates used to initally build the site?

Tags: templating

Our website was created by someone who is no longer with the business. I can edit existing data, however am trying to access the original templates used when the site was originally built in order to change a few things. Where would I find these?

Answer (score 5):

I suppose you need access via FTP to the templates directory - which by default is `craft/templates`. Once you have access to that, you'll have access to the site templates. Do you have FTP access?

There's no way in Craft to view your templates through the Control Panel interface.

Comment: No, I don't think I do. I can't see them anywhere anyway. Is there any way to enable this and allow me access?

Comment: @Jacqui most webhosts or servers have FTP enabled by default, but you need the credentials to log in.

Comment: Hello! I've accessed the templates! So now i've changed what I need to .. how the heck do I upload it to amend the website???

Comment: Traditionally uploads via ftp. But bare in mind the templates may be configured to be accessed from a directory other than the public directory....

Comment: I'd suggest getting familiar with the [Craft documentation](https://craftcms.com/docs/introduction). Or if you need a bit more help, [Mijingo do some decent courses](https://mijingo.com/products/screencasts/up-and-running-with-craft/) to get you started.